# Are SAS Data Storage Options designed for Big Data?

Tags: dataset, sas

I understand that SAS has some data storage options in the form of

- **Default Storage** tables or SAS datasets - in the SAS library.
- **Multi-dimensional Storage** cubes - in the OLAP Server.
- **Third Party Storage** - into external databases like SQL Server ,Oracle, DB2, Teradata etc.
- **Parallel Storage** - ?

*My Questions are:*

1. Are any of these data storage options designed for moderately big data i.e. data over a million observations?

   - Is this quantification at all affected by the machine that SAS is
     running on?
   - If yes,then let's imagine a computer with 4 cores and 16GB Memory.

*I've worked with SAS tables before, but they were never larger than a couple hundred thousand observations.*

2. The Parallel Storage is supposed to be a high speed alternative for processing very large data sets.

   - Are these data sets stored in the SAS Library / Server etc?
   - Can Parallel Storage help in scaling to data over a million records?
3. Finally, do these data storage options make SAS function like a Database Management System - like SQL Server?

Comment: This question really focuses on how SAS works, rather than an underlying statistical issue, so may not be on-topic here - have a look at our [help/on-topic] for more information. I'm not sure, but this might be a better fit for Data Science SE than it is for Cross Validated.

Comment: @Silverfish, Thanks for the help. But, I'm not getting any views or response here? What can I do?

Comment: Have a look at [this help page](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to update as much I can. Meanwhile, IF you think the question is worth answering, please up-vote it so it becomes visible.

Comment: The storage of data isn't the question.  The question depends entirely on how much of the processing can run in database.  SAS has some capabilities to run in database, as well as run those processes in parallel, but it's a pretty limited list of whathe SAS procedures can do so.